# Rule syntax to parse string decorated by double braces in Spirit Qi

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to parse multiline content that include the following pattern: `{{some_dynamic_string}}`

I tried defining the rule as follows, but the parse fails:

```
token_rule = qi::lit("{{") >> +qi::char_ >> qi::lit("}}");
```

The debug output for parsing shows the following:

```
<start_rule>
  <try>{{foo|bar}}\n</try>
  <token_rule>
    <try>{{foo|bar}}\n</try>
    <fail/>
  </token_rule>
  <fail/>
</start_rule>
```

It is trying to parse the first line in the multiline content, which happens to include the pattern by itself. What is wrong with the rule? Do I need to exclude `{{` and `}}` from the second item in the sequence? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prevent `char_` from matching where `}}` would match.

The simplest way:

```
token_rule = "{{" >> +(qi::char_ - "}}") >> "}}";
```

### DEMO

Full demo with debug info for comparison:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afa600ccfe14e90a)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

using string = std::string;
using strings = std::vector<std::string>;

template <typename It>
struct Grammar: qi::grammar<It, strings()>
{
    Grammar() : Grammar::base_type(start) {

        start       = qi::skip(qi::space) [tokens_rule];

        tokens_rule = *token_rule;
        token_rule  = "{{" >> +(qi::char_ - "}}") >> "}}";

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(tokens_rule)(token_rule))
    }
  private:
    // implicit lexemes
    qi::rule<It, strings()> start;
    qi::rule<It, strings(), qi::space_type> tokens_rule;
    qi::rule<It, string()> token_rule;
};

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    Grammar<It> g;
    for (std::string const input : { "{{a}}", " {{a b}} {{more}}\n", "{{a{b} }}" })
    {
        It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
        strings parsed;
        if (parse(f, l, g, parsed)) {
            std::cout << "Parsed '" << input << "'\n";
            for(auto& tok : parsed)
                std::cout << " -- '" << tok << "'\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
        }

        if (f != l)
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Printing

```
Parsed '{{a}}'
 -- 'a'
Parsed ' {{a b}} {{more}}
'
 -- 'a b'
 -- 'more'
Parsed '{{a{b} }}'
 -- 'a{b} '
```

With debug info:

```xml
<start>
  <try>{{a}}</try>
  <tokens_rule>
    <try>{{a}}</try>
    <token_rule>
      <try>{{a}}</try>
      <success></success>
      <attributes>[[a]]</attributes>
    </token_rule>
    <token_rule>
      <try></try>
      <fail/>
    </token_rule>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[[a]]]</attributes>
  </tokens_rule>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[[a]]]</attributes>
</start>
Parsed '{{a}}'
 -- 'a'
<start>
  <try> {{a b}} {{more}}\n</try>
  <tokens_rule>
    <try> {{a b}} {{more}}\n</try>
    <token_rule>
      <try>{{a b}} {{more}}\n</try>
      <success> {{more}}\n</success>
      <attributes>[[a,  , b]]</attributes>
    </token_rule>
    <token_rule>
      <try>{{more}}\n</try>
      <success>\n</success>
      <attributes>[[m, o, r, e]]</attributes>
    </token_rule>
    <token_rule>
      <try></try>
      <fail/>
    </token_rule>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[[a,  , b], [m, o, r, e]]]</attributes>
  </tokens_rule>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[[a,  , b], [m, o, r, e]]]</attributes>
</start>
Parsed ' {{a b}} {{more}}
'
 -- 'a b'
 -- 'more'
<start>
  <try>{{a{b} }}</try>
  <tokens_rule>
    <try>{{a{b} }}</try>
    <token_rule>
      <try>{{a{b} }}</try>
      <success></success>
      <attributes>[[a, {, b, },  ]]</attributes>
    </token_rule>
    <token_rule>
      <try></try>
      <fail/>
    </token_rule>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[[a, {, b, },  ]]]</attributes>
  </tokens_rule>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[[a, {, b, },  ]]]</attributes>
</start>
Parsed '{{a{b} }}'
 -- 'a{b} '
```

Comment: Added a full demo [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81feed811b7e8f47)

Comment: Just fixed the attribute handling in the demo http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afa600ccfe14e90a

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if confix is deprecated in favor of writing this type of rule? The 1.65 repo docs seem to be busted.

Comment: @PrasadSilva is not deprecated but it has never been supported because it's part of the [Spirit Repository](1_65_1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/repository.html), online docs are borked indeed though Google finds pdf copies of them floating around

Answer (score 1):

I was able to parse the line successfully with the [Qi Confix Parser Directive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/spirit_repository/qi_components/directives/confix.html).

```
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_confix.hpp>
namespace qi_repo = boost::spirit::repository;

token_rule = qi_repo::confix("{{", "}}")[+(qi::char_ - "}}")];
```